# copy files from docker container to host, or mirror a folder

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have this docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  myserver:
    image: <some image>
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./res:/tmp/configs
      - ./myfolder:/tmp/logs
```

Should I expect to see the files that are in /tmp/logs inside the container, in the host folder 'myfolder'?
'myfolder' is empty and I want it to be updated with the contents of the /tmp/logs folder in the container.

Comment: Updates in `myfolder` should be reflected in `/tmp/logs` and vice versa. Is that NOT what you see ?

Comment: ...except, at startup time, the contents of the host's `./myfolder` directory replace whatever was in `/tmp/logs` in the image; but once the container is created, the host and container directories are the same and writes to one should be visible in the other.

Comment: @Philippe I see the that the folder is created in the container, but if I add files to it, nothing happens on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is using full path for the host path.

`C:\myfolder` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting purposes, I post this as an answer instead of comment.

Can you put following in `test.sh` on the host?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

testdir=/tmp/docker-compose

rm -rf "$testdir"; mkdir -p "$testdir"/{myfolder,res}
cd "$testdir"

cat << EOF > docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  myserver:
    image: debian
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./res:/tmp/configs
      - ./myfolder:/tmp/logs
    command: sleep inf
EOF

docker-compose up
```

and run `bash test.sh` on the host and see if it works. host dir is `/tmp/docker-compose/myfolder`.

Comment: I can't have this host dir, it's Windows.

Comment: Try any windows directory, create `myfolder` and `res` directories and run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: That's what I did, myfolder stays empty.

Comment: Can you post you docker, docker-compose and windows version ?

Comment: Sure - Windows 11 Pro, version 21H2. Docker desktop version 20.10.21, API version 1.41. Docker compose version 2.13.0.

Comment: I tested on Windows 10 22H2. You put `linux` tag, can you test on Linux ?

Comment: The Linux tag is because it's a Linux container. On a Windows host. I don't have a Linux to test it on : /.